# Convert key-value JSON to object and refer individual values directly

Tags: php, json

I am making a web app. In one part of it, I have JS send a string(in json format) to PHP.

The value php receives is:

```
{"date":"24-03-2014","Cars":["Cheap","Expensive"]}
```

Now, this is saved in a variable `$meta`. The problem I am facing is, as to how do I convert this string into an object and reference each individual entry separately.

I have tried `json_decode` and `json_encode`

and then I have referenced each variable using `$meta.["date"]` and `$meta.date` but nothing seams to work. I am getting just `{` as the output.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '{"date":"24-03-2014","Cars":["Cheap","Expensive"]}';
$obj = json_decode($str);

echo $obj->date;
// 24-03-2014
```

Comment: I am getting a blank line as output. Any guesses as to what's wrong?

Comment: Try print_r($obj) and see the output?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a `$my_obj = json_decode($_POST['jsonstring'], 1);` (true supply means it'll be returned as an assoviative array) should be the way to go. If I were you I'd probably try a `var_dump($my_obj);` to see what actually comes through. If it doesn't work you'll want to make sure that you correctly submit a valid json string, e.g. `JSON.stringify();`

Comment: I am getting a blank line as output. Any guesses as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the PHP doc page for `json_decode` [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

By default, unless you pass `true` as the second parameter for `json_decode`, the function call will return an object, which you can access the members of by using:

```
$meta->date
```

The arrow operator will allow you to access object values, not the square brackets or a dot.

Comment: I am getting a blank line as output. Any guesses as to what's wrong?